# getting rank of specific user with windows function in djago

Tags: python, django, orm

this is my query which gives me the ranking of all user:

```
rank = Wallet.objects.filter(type=0, space_id=space.id).annotate(
            rank=Window(
                expression=DenseRank(),
                order_by=F('point_amount').desc(),
            )
        ).order_by('rank').values("user__id","user__username","rank")
```

but how can i get rank of specific user in this query?(i don't want to handle this whit python)

i already try this:

```
rank = Wallet.objects.filter(type=0, space_id=space.id, user_id=user.id).annotate(
            rank=Window(
                expression=DenseRank(),
                order_by=F('point_amount').desc(),
            )
        ).order_by('rank').values("user__id","user__username","rank")
```

but it gives me rank 1 which is not correct

note:
this raw query gives me the right answer but i don't konw how to convert this in to django orm query

````
query = f'''
            SELECT
                FIND_IN_SET(
                    `transaction_wallet`.`point_amount`,
                    (
                        SELECT
                        GROUP_CONCAT(`transaction_wallet`.`point_amount` ORDER BY `transaction_wallet`.`point_amount` DESC)
                        FROM `transaction_wallet`
                        WHERE `transaction_wallet`.`type` = 0 AND `transaction_wallet`.`space_id` = {space.id}
                    )
                ) AS `rank`
            FROM
                `transaction_wallet`
            WHERE
                `transaction_wallet`.`type` = 0 AND `transaction_wallet`.`space_id` = {space.id} AND `transaction_wallet`.`user_id` = {self.id};
        '''
    ```
````

Comment: Given you `.order_by('rank')`, why not just use `.order_by('-point_amount')`?

Comment: The reason it uses `rank=1`, is because it ranks on the *filtered* set, so only for that user, and that space id, and that type.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem nope. ```order_by('-point_amount')``` doesn't work

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem everytime i add user to filter it gives me rank 1. no matter which user rank i want to get. i already know why this happen because i'm using window function. but i can't find the proper query!

Answer (score -1):

Django querysets are lazy. They are evaluated when needed. This means when your query is executed the `user_id` filter is limiting the queryset to a single object and then is the window function evaluated. The result is the `rank` value of `1`.
To work around this you have to first build your query without the `user_id` filter, make django execute the query (including the annotation) and afterwards apply the `user_id` filter.

```
# Step 1: Build the annotated query
rank = (Wallet
        .objects
        .filter(type=0, space_id=space.id)
        .annotate(rank=Window(expression=DenseRank(),
                              order_by=F('point_amount').desc())
        .order_by('rank'))
# Step 2: Evaluate the query
rank.count()

# Step 3: Now apply the filter
ranked_user_wallet = rank.filter(user_id=user.id)

# Now ranked_user_wallet is a queryset of Wallet objects
# of the desired user with the correct rank annotation applied
```

Comment: this doesn't work. still gives me rank 1  on step 3. i think despite you evaluate on step 2, because of caching mechanism whenever you call rank queryset it is unevaluated